# Convert scala future to Listenable Future

Tags: scala

I want to use the Futures.addCalback method in my scala application, but this method takes an instance of ListenableFuture but I am dealing with scala future. Can someone please help me how to cast scala future to ListenableFuture?

```
     `Futures.addCallback(futureResult, callback)`
```

It is giving me compile time error as futureResult is scala future, not ListenableFuture which the method is expecting.
I have searched google. But all links show results only for casting listenableFuture to scala future, not the other way.

Comment: Just use `futureResult.onSuccess { ... }` you don't need `addCallback`.

Comment: Where is this listenable future coming from ?